# Examples for output_query with PIG and Cassandra CqlStorage

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig, cql3

I am trying to write data to Cassandra CQL 3 Table using:

STORE G INTO 'cql://keyapse/col_family?output_query=not sure what goes here' USING CqlStorage();

What does the output_query look like:

UPDATE col_family SET col1=$0, col2=$3 WHERE KEY=$2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care on both: the storage URL and the data preparation.
This is an example that should work.

Suppose you need to insert data in the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  row_id text PRIMARY KEY,

  value1 text,

  value2 int
);
```

You need to prepare the data like this:

```
data_to_insert = FOREACH some_set_of_data GENERATE 

    TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('row_id',row_id)), TOTUPLE(value1, value2) ;
```

Finally the storing statement will be:

```
STORE data_to_insert INTO 'cql://my/example?output_query=update example set value1 @ # , value2 @ #' USING CqlStorage();
```

Comment: Kernald, can you add this to the comments on, http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-table-support-in-hadoop-pig-and-hive.  Or I would be happy too for you.

Comment: Cassandra 1.2.10 breaks this method of creating the statement. It now expects the query to be URL encoded. Your example would become: STORE data_to_insert INTO 'cql://my/example?output_query=update+example+set value1+%3D+%3F+,+value2+%3D+%3F' USING CqlStorage();

Answer (score 0):

This blog has some details, but no specific examples:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-table-support-in-hadoop-pig-and-hive

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a brief how to on using PIG as a Data loader for Cassandra using CQL3.

http://www.schappet.com/pig_cassandra_bulk_load

Basic setup includes the info from @Kernald

```
STORE data_to_insert INTO
  'cql://myschema/example?output_query=update example set value1 @ #,value2 @ #' USING CqlStorage();
```